# Translational (path-defined) objects?

Tags: x3d

I heard about translational objects, i.e. objects created by translating a flat shape along a line segment. Are these supported in X3D, and if yes, how to define them?

Comment: Do you mean extrusion? You can find the definition in the standard at http://www.web3d.org/documents/specifications/19775-1/V3.2/Part01/components/geometry3D.html#Extrusion

Comment: Ah OK, thanks! Always helps to know the actual name of something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, they're called extrusional objects. The commentor also provided [this link](http://www.web3d.org/documents/specifications/19775-1/V3.2/Part01/components/geometry3D.html#Extrusion) to the documentation.

Probably would've found it by myself if I had known what they're called. My bad.